# implicit function thm and chain rule

Tags: implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

$f(x,y,z)=x^3-2y^2+z^2$, $x_0=(1,1,1)$ and $g(1,1)=1$, $f(x,y,g(x,y))=0$

find $g_x(1,1), g_y(1,1)$ using chain rule, are there any other ways to find it?

my attempt at it with respect to x, I think is not very good,

$$x^3-2y^2+(g(x,y))^2=0 \rightarrow 3x^2+2(g(x,y))g_x(x,y)=0$$

Then solve for $g_x(1,1)$?  What about the implicit function theorem?  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given:
$${x_0} = (1,1,1),f(x,y,z) = {x^3} - 2{y^2} + z$$
with
$$f({x_0}) = 0$$
and
$$\nabla f = (3{x^2}, - 4y,1)$$
with
$$\nabla f({x_0}) = (3, - 4,1) \ne \vec 0$$
Then, implicit fuction theorem says: Near ${x_0}$

$$\begin{gathered}
  f(x,y,g(x,y)) \equiv 0 \hfill \\
  {x^3} - 2{y^2} + g(x,y) \equiv 0 \hfill \\
  g(x,y) =  - {x^3} + 2{y^2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
so:
$$\begin{gathered}
  \nabla g = ( - 3x,4y) \hfill \\
  \frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial x}}(x,y) =  - 3x,\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial y}}(x,y) = 4y \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$
with
$$\begin{gathered}
  \frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial x}}(1,1) =  - 3 \hfill \\
  \frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial y}}(1,1) = 4 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$